# Mudança de CSS por meio de Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, acessibilidade

Para aplicar recursos de acessibilidade em um site (contraste/fonte maior/fonte menor), criei arquivos .css alternativos com a formatação desejada e chamei esses arquivos por meio de um javascript. Entretanto, principalmente quando a conexão é lenta, quando a função é chamada, a página fica por 1 segundo sem css e depois a formatação é aplicada. Essa "piscada" dá uma atrapalhada na usabilidade sabe?

Mas não sei como resolver. Alguma sugestão?

Essa é a função que altera os css de acordo com o botão clicado:

```
function fontegrande()
{   
var css = document.querySelector('#css');


document.cookie = "fonte=grande";
    var fonte = Cookies.get("fonte");
    var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");
    if(fonte=="grande"){
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssaumento.css');
    }
    if (contraste=="contrasteativo") 
    {
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssaumentocontraste.css');
    }

}

function fontepequena ()
{       
var css = document.querySelector('#css');
var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");
    //Cookies.set("fonte","pequena", { expires: 365 });
document.cookie = "fonte=pequena";
var fonte = Cookies.get("fonte");
    if(fonte=="pequena"){
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssmenor.css');
    }
    if (contraste=="contrasteativo") 
    {
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssmenorcontraste.css');
    }
}

function fontenormal ()
{   
    var css = document.querySelector('#css');
    var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");
    document.cookie = "fonte=normal";
    var fonte = Cookies.get("fonte");
    if(fonte=="normal"){
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/Application.css');
    }
    if (contraste=="contrasteativo")
    {
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/csscontraste.css')
    }

}

function contraste ()
{
    var css = document.querySelector('#css');
    var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");

    var fonte = Cookies.get("fonte");

    if (contraste != "contrasteativo")
    {
        document.cookie = "contraste=contrasteativo";
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/csscontraste.css');
        if (fonte=="pequena")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssmenorcontraste.css');
        }
        if (fonte=="grande")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssaumentocontraste.css');
        }
        if (fonte=="normal")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/csscontraste.css');
        }
    }

else
    if (contraste != "contrasteinativo")
    {
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/Application.css');
        document.cookie = "contraste=contrasteinativo";
        if (fonte == "pequena")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssmenor.css');
        }
        if (fonte=="grande")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssaumento.css');
        }
        if (fonte=="normal")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/Application.css');       
        }
    }   

}
```

Essa é a função chamada no carregamento da página para checar qual css está ativo:

```
function checafontegrande()
{   
    var css = document.querySelector('#css');
    var fonte = Cookies.get("fonte");
    var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");
    if(fonte=="grande"){
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssaumento.css');
    }
    if (contraste=="contrasteativo") 
    {
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssaumentocontraste.css');
    }

}

function checafontepequena ()
{       
var css = document.querySelector('#css');
var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");
var fonte = Cookies.get("fonte");
    if(fonte=="pequena"){
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssmenor.css');
    }
    if (contraste=="contrasteativo") 
    {
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssmenorcontraste.css');
    }
}

function checafontenormal ()
{   
    var css = document.querySelector('#css');
    var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");
    var fonte = Cookies.get("fonte");
    if(fonte=="normal"){
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/Application.css');
    }
    if (contraste=="contrasteativo")
    {
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/csscontraste.css')
    }

}

function checacontraste ()
{
    var css = document.querySelector('#css');
    var contraste = Cookies.get("contraste");
    var fonte = Cookies.get("fonte");

    if (contraste != "contrasteativo")
    {
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/Application.css');
        if (fonte=="pequena")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssmenor.css');
        }
        if (fonte=="grande")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssaumento.css');
        }
        if (fonte=="normal")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/Application.css');
        }
    }

else
    if (contraste != "contrasteinativo")
    {
        css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/csscontraste.css');   
        if (fonte == "pequena")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssmenorcontraste.css');
        }
        if (fonte=="grande")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/cssaumentocontraste.css');
        }
        if (fonte=="normal")
        {
            css.setAttribute('href', '/Content/csscontraste.css');      
        }
    }   

}
```

Coloquei essa de checagem assim:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        checafontegrande();
        checafontepequena();
        checafontenormal();
        checacontraste();
    }
      );
```

Comment: Inclua o seu código à pergunta

Comment: Certo, inseri Leandro

Comment: Tenho uma sugestão: ao trocar o CSS,  para não exibir o conteúdo sem CSS, você poderia fazer algo do tipo (usando jQuery): `$('body').addClass('sumir');` - depois do comando de trocar o CSS, remova a classe: `$('body').removeClass('sumir');` - essa classe deverá estar em outro arquivo CSS ou definida no início assim: `.sumir { display: none; }` - Pode ser que ajude. No entanto, em vez de mostrar o conteúdo sem o CSS a página ficaria em branco.

Comment: @RodrigoTognin, mostrar uma tela de loading, antes de carregar o conteúdo do site, ou seja, o usuário irá visualizar somente uma imagem gif ou um texto, até que o site esteja totalmente carregado.

Comment: faz o  seguinte usa o $.ajax pega o valor de cada css, salva em uma variavel,  ai quando trocar você não precisa buscar no  servidor novamente so pega o que está salvo, ai  você escreve em  um <style id="x"></style>